# mongorestore - AtlasError - getting non-bucket system collections is unsupported

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

> Failed: (AtlasError) getting non-bucket system collections is unsupported

I'm trying to use `mongorestore` to migrate data from one database to another. Both on Atlas. The dump is working fine, but `mongorestore` is outputting the below messages. I have no clue what this means and a google search renders nothing remotely close. I've added hyphens to the beginning of each line of the output to make it more readable.

```
-- using write concern: &{majority false 0}
-- will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
-- connected to node type: replset
-- The --db and --collection flags are deprecated for this use-case; please use --nsInclude instead, i.e. with --nsInclude=${DATABASE}.${COLLECTION}
-- got error from options parsing: (AtlasError) getting non-bucket system collections is unsupported
-- Failed: (AtlasError) getting non-bucket system collections is unsupported
-- 0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

The command I'm running

```
mongorestore --uri="mongodb+srv://username:password@hostname.mongodb.net/$DEV_DATABASE" \
  --preserveUUID \
  --drop \
  --nsFrom="$PROD_DATABASE.*" \
  --nsTo="$DEV_DATABASE.*" \
  --verbose \
  "dump/$PROD_DATABASE"
```

I've also tried creating an archive file with `mongodump` and using that with `--archive="filename"`, as well as piping stdout to `mongorestore`. I've also checked that the user I'm using has the correct privileges. They have the role of `Atlas admin`, which I'm assuming is correct. The dev cluster I'm trying to restore to is an M0 if that makes any difference.

I should also point out that I have minimal Mongo management experience, so I'm sure there's something I've overlooked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think Atlas lets you tweak the collection UUIDs.  Try without the `--preserveUUID`

Comment: I'll give it a shot, and report back

Comment: Well what do you know. That was it! I wish the error message from atlas wasn't so cryptic, I could have had this solved two days ago. Please post that as the answer so I can give you credit. Thanks for help your @Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB records the collection UUIDs in a separate system collection.

The `--preserveUUID` option instructs mongorestore to create the collection, and force it to use the UUID from the source system.

The error message indicates that Atlas is refusing to allow you to access or modify that system collection.

Run without the `--preserveUUID` option when restoring to Atlas.